# How to tell what libraries a PCL application needs

Tags: c++, static-linking, point-cloud-library

Because of my particular build I have the issue where I want to minimize the number of PCL libs that are built. I also have the requirement that the PCL libs are static due to funny behavior with boost on my particular OS (QNX).

**I want to know how to tell what libraries PCL ICP uses?**

So there are some obvious ones like *registration*, *common* and *kdtree* But i have a feeling that extra libraries will be required by those libraries.

I have a full install with an ICP example built however because it is statically linked i cannot check this with `ldd`.

What I can do to find out and what I have been doing is to move all of the libraries from `/usr/local/lib` to some temporary folder and then moving the ones the compiler complains about back in until it builds. But surely there is a better way than this?

I have looked through the documentation but i cannot find anything obvious about which libs are required. I would like to know the procedure for checking this in case I need to do so again for another application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation of the registration module](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/a02953.html), the requirements are named:

- common
- kdtree
- sample_consensus
- features

Compiling pcl using cmake (as proposed in the docs), e.g. ccmake could also tell you which dependencies are missing, if you try to compile `BUILD_registration`.

Comment: @Ben So your question is answered?